# Objective-C File Creation Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, file-io, nsstring, nsdata

I am making a simple command line tool where the user enters a username and password (I don't care about encryption
as this is only an exercise) and their age and this data is written to a file. This is the code I have:

```
    char username[40];
    char password[40];
    int age = 0;
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/config.txt", NSHomeDirectory()];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc]init];

    //Username Input
    NSLog(@"Pick a username (less then 40 letters):");
    scanf("%s", username);
    NSString *usernameString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:username
                                                            length:39 
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    //Password Input
    NSLog(@"Pick a password (less then 40 letters):");
    scanf("%s", password);
    NSString *passwordString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:password
                                                        length:39 
                                                      encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //Age Input
    NSLog(@"What's your age?");
    scanf("%i", &age);

    NSString *finalContents = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@\n%i", usernameString, passwordString, age];
    NSData *dataContent = [finalContents dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [fileManager createFileAtPath:path contents:dataContent attributes: nil];
```

When I open up the file produced, it has the content:

```
(null)
(null)
18
```

I inputted a string less then 40 characters for both the username and password and the number 18 for the age, so it appears that only the age is working. 
Thanks in advanced.

EDIT: The file has the content "(null) (null) 18" with line breaks in between, but they are not showing up in my post.

Comment: First, validate what you intend to write to the file.  `NSLog("finalContents was: %@", finalContents);`  Does that show the string you expect?

Comment: The hardcoded `length:39` seems suspicious to me. You should rather use `strlen(username)` and `strlen(password)` respectively. The uninitialized bytes after the `'\0'` can form invalid UTF-8 sequences...

Comment: I understand, but user will usually answer something shorter, so the bytes after what user enters are unitialized. I'm not sure if constructor of `NSString` ignores them after the `'\0'` or not. If not you have trouble. Passing real length of the C string (which should be <= 39) is safer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `stringWithCString:encoding:`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I replaced the `[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes...` methods with this one and then appended them together to then convert into an NSData object.